# PHP page=home script, need some assistance

Tags: php

I'm currently rocking this script:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('home', $_GET)) {
    echo 'home goes here';
}
?>
```

.. which requires the following URL to show:

```
/index.php?home
```

I've seen on alot of sites this URL:

```
/index.php?type=home
```

**QUESTION:** How can I transform the script posted above into the type=home URL?

Comment: `if(isset($_GET["type"]) && $_GET["type"] === "home")` ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 Awesome, thanks for the answer. Have a good weekend!

Comment: You're welcome! You too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `$_GET["type"]` instead of `$_GET`. You have to check if `$_GET["type"]` exists: `if (isset($_GET["type"])) { /* do something */ }`